# checking DBNULL image exception

Tags: asp.net, dbnull

```
<asp:Image ID="lbl_photo" runat ="server" ImageUrl ='<%# string.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,"+ Convert.ToBase64String ((Byte[])Eval("photo"))) %>'
                        Width="100px" Height="100px"></asp:Image>

<asp:Image ID="lbl_photo" runat ="server" ImageUrl ='data:image/jpg;base64,<%# Eval("photo") != System.DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("photo")) : string.Empty %>' alt="image"
                        Width="100px" Height="100px"></asp:Image>
```

Hi,  I need to display a image from DB in grid the above syntax can read and display the images if its not null, and if its null it should throw an exception. So, I modified the condition with checking dbnull, so now it is getting all the data without any exceptions, but the images are not displayed. Can anyone help with the correct syntax for this?

Comment: could anyone tell , whats wrong in the syntax

Comment: could anyone tell , whats wrong in the syntax